# What can I submerge my keyboard circuit board in that would remove the corrosion from it?

Tags: pcb, repair, keyboard, corrosion, cleaning

The contacts are between two thin plastic(?). In order to expose the print, I'd have to peel them apart. That's a lot of work since I'd have to perfectly align them to put them back together.

What can I submerge the circuit board in as-is that would remove the corrosion/rust without having to rub/brush it off?

Here's a picture of the board.[image]

Comment: Corrosion compounds don't just magically vanish when dissolved by a solvent. They are still there. Without peeling back the print, the dissolved corrosion compounds will stay beneath the print, as will any solvent that got under there.

Comment: Your plan may be naive on property of materials for solvents and etchants and Your details are missing on thickness of materials and oxidants, insulators and agitation / removal would be critical if dissolving plastic

Comment: there should be aligning pins on the keyboard to keep the two sheets in correct position

Comment: Such sheets are typically used in very cheap membrane keyboards. Just replace the keyboard, it'll cost less then any chemical you'd buy.

Comment: It looks like a laptop keyboard.

Comment: Laptop keyboards are pretty inexpensive. Search e*** for your laptop model no + "keyboard" and you'll probably find a new replacement for under $20.